# Trying to control text's position inside input

Tags: html, css

so Iv'e made an input that it's height is "300px" what means that its pretty big, and when I type a text the input it's starts from the middle of the input and not from the left top. How do I do it?

```
text-align: left;
height: 300px;
```

Comment: Could you share your html code please?

Comment: The impression I get is that you are trying to create a `textarea` instead of an `input`.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds suspiciously like you might actually want a textarea instead of an input. But if you really want an input, so that only one line of text can be entered, in combination with this rather weird display requirement - then use a padding-bottom instead of height.

Comment: @Azametzin From what Iv'e seen at google searching I think that'll be the best solution. But can I get it's value same as I do with an Input? *Edited message* I have picked a text area from bootstrap thank you. I'll try act with it like an input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `padding` instead of height.
Something along the lines of this would suffice:

```
input{
    padding-bottom: 280px; /* change this depending on your requirements */
}
```

Although I don't recommended this. It's very tacky and un-user friendly. As the comments suggested, you should have a look into **HTML**'s native `textarea` element.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you were looking for but consider it.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("demo");

function getValue() {
  alert(textarea.value); // Works just like a text input!!!
}
```

```css
#demo {
  height: 300px;
  resize: horizontal;
  /* Considering you have defined a height */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to-your/css-file.css">
  -->
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="demo">And yes you can get the value of a textarea just like a text input!</textarea>
  <button onclick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
</body>

</html>
```